# Regular Expression on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have snippet javascript (web) but since i try to use RegExpression it should work almost the same.

I have a string with some coordinates in it seperated by a space charakter (last coordinate has no space after it).

```
var coords = "0:0 0:0:0 1:0:1 0:0:0:1 0:0:1 0:0:2";
var part = "0:0";
```

I want to have all the coordinates beginning with the value of part ("0:0") plus ":" and the next coordinate number. If a coordinate matches but has more than one additional "coordinate-dimensions" it shouldn't show...

For example it should show 0:0:0, 0:0:1 and 0:0:2 but NOT 0:0 (because to less dimension), 0:0:0:1 (because if the additional dimension)

What I tryed is something like:

```
var reg = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(0:0:\\d\\s)", "g");
alert(coords .match(reg));
```

But it seems not to work propperly.

Anyone has an idea?!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
"(?:^|\\s)(0:0:\\d)(?=\\s|$)"
```

Comment: when i try ur snipped it prints out only 0:0:0, 0:0:1 but where is the 0:0:2?

Comment: @marius Ah! A minor mistake. Edited the regex. Will work now.

Comment: i've just checked there is still a mistake in it... at be beginning of every coordinate there is a whitespace in it. like " 0:0:0", " 0:0:1". Someone has an idea how to cut it out?

Comment: @marius You need to get the group 1 out of it. Javascript doesn't support look-behind. So, you have no other option.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with this, could you show any code-snippet? kind regards